# I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3 - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have an app that is published on the play store and is enabled to show ads. I wanted to release an update since I've added some new features.
However, the live ads are not loading, whilst the test ads are working fine. After I looked into this issue, I learned that the error code 3 represents no available ads at the moment. But what's strange is that the version of the app currently live on the play store shows real ads perfectly fine( the ads with the same pub ID). Also, I'd like to acknowledge that the AdMob account and the Ad units are a year old.
But when I'm using the same ad units in the newer version( yet to be rolled out), I'm getting this error
`I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3`. It's been over 3-4 days since I'm getting this error and haven't fixed this until now.
Other than feature addition, the following are the changes made to the app:

1. version code
2. version name
3. Target SDK version
4. Minimum SDK version
5. Migrated to androidX ( due to some library incompatibility), live ads weren't showing before the migration also.
6. Updated **play-services-ads** from **16.0.0** to **19.1.0**

What do I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update for the above error

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed. The issue was quite weird, the ads failed to show during local testing, but did show up during internal/closed testing, and also works just well in production.

Comment: It not worked for me in production as well